# Women's toilet when there is no woman around

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, gender

I work at a company which recently hired a female developer for the first time.

We currently have two bathrooms available: One with two male standing toilet and a regular toilet (with a door), and another with just one regular toilet.

Up to now, since we were all men, we used both bathrooms. Now, we have put a sign at each bathroom door to indicate gender.

But it seems to be fine for us employees to use it while our female coworker is not in the office.

I've talked about this to the manager as I find this anti-hygienic. He said it is anti-hygienic but due to our current situation (almost 15 males everyday at work) it is the best thing they can do. That it is everybody's responsibility to leave the bathrooms clean.

Also, I think the manager hinted me that as long as she doesn't know, there should be no problem. The expression for this was:

> *Ojos que no ven, corazón que no siente*.
>
> Google Translate: *Out of sight out of mind.*

I could translate it but I don't know if it will lose the meaning.

That exactly is what keeps bothering me.
How is this handled around the world?

Comment: What  do you do if a female visitor asks to use a restroom?

Comment: I'm confused by the "anti-hygenic" part of the question. Toilets are toilets. Did you not use the same toilet as your own mother and father? Have you never used a gender-neutral bathroom?

Comment: As a comment, we should be aware of the distinction between *gender* and *sex* to convey the actual meaning of what we want to specify.

Comment: How does every male employee define when she's "not in the office" - is that exclusively when she's out for the day (what if she comes in late), or does that include e.g. when she goes to lunch? Seems very prone to error.

Comment: In many offices I've worked in I'm the only woman.  I have no issue with the toilets being gender neutral, but if that is the decision, then the signs should reflect it so everyone is on the same page.  If management has decided to make the toilets gender-specific for whatever reason, then it should be respected and perhaps discussed with management to consider changing.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan there are 2, (cleaning lady and an accounting something, but they only come for a few hours a few days a week,  cant really tell what happens in those moments)

Comment: @Dukeling "not in the office" i ment after hour, when she leaves the office until the next day

Comment: Since the toilet in question is a single stall, I'd personally consider it fair game to use. At any time. I can understand the awkwardness of a woman having to pass occupied urinals on her way to a stall. But this can't happen in this setup.

Comment: @trap_robot It looks like you have created multiple accounts - one posted the question and the other has made comments. I recommend looking at [this help page](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge the accounts.

Comment: In my office, we have two single toilets, marked as male and female, one each. It was always clear that both toilets would be used by both genders when we only had a sectretary, and now that we have a female developer it's still the same. If you've done it for now, just keep doing it. She will complain if she has a problem with that.

Comment: "as I find this anti-hygienic" - in what way?  The female will get some disgusting contamination from men using her toilet seat, or vice-versa?  Are the men actually that disgusting compared to the female (or vice-versa)? This sounds like "cooties"-phobia, as it is stated. (if you are a non-English-speaker as a first language, kids in pre-school refer to something as "cooties" as imaginary girl-germs or boy-germs, for a reason not to interact with the opposite gender).

Answer (score 24):

> But it seems to be fine for us employees to use it while our female coworker is not in the office.

Personally I do *not* consider this fine. It is in a way a **double standard**; respect the bathroom sign when she is around but ignore it when she is not. What is the purpose of the sign then, just to signal *her* what bathroom to use?

> Also , i think the manager hinted me that as long as she doesn't know, there should be no problem.

I consider this as **not being honest and clear** with your colleagues, something that should be done all the time. Again, what if it was the other way around? How would you feel if she used the men's bathroom without your knowledge?

... Anyways, I believe it is time for your company to specify exclusive bathrooms for both sexes, as it seems now it is growing and should consider its infrastructure capabilities for the future. Another option is to consider a bathroom that can be used for both sexes (as pointed out in the comments). These options seem to be the standard way in many places (not only companies).

Comment: +1 "Another option is to consider a bathroom that can be used for both sexes" please create gender-neutral restrooms as they are the best way to be inclusive of non-binary individuals. If local law allows, make all restrooms gender-neutral if you can.

Comment: @2rs2ts Laws aside, we unfortunately still live in a world where gender-neutral restrooms are very much frowned upon by some and implementing them may very well make the one woman being forced to share a bathroom with 15 men extremely uncomfortable. It's definitely a sensitive topic one shouldn't just jump head-first into.

Comment: Cant mark as answered since i asked without creating an account. But i think you share a point i am really bothered which is transparency and honesty. I think that putting a multigender sign in the bathroom door would do just fine

Comment: @trap_robot: If you do that, MAKE SURE you clear it with HR first (or at least the female colleague). You and your coworkers may not consider it an issue, but she might (since she's the only female in the office). But otherwise, the gender-neutral option seems a good one to me as well.

Comment: @2rs2ts even though I'm all for gender neutral things, OP describes two standing toilets without a door. This means anyone walking in that bathroom could see someone else's penis and this is obviously not accepted. OP's restrooms are not designed in a gender neutral way and I highly doubt the company is willing to invest in changing the layout of the restrooms.

Comment: I think the decision of whether to do separate men's and women's rooms, or a men's room (with urinals) and a gender neutral room depends on the the actual layout of the bathroom, which is not clear to me. A single one-room bathroom which locks can easily be turned into a gender-neutral room. An open access bathroom with sinks and a single stall would be much more difficult (politically) to share, in which case I would recommend keeping the two restrooms distinct.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: My understanding is there are two rooms: One with two urinals plus a stall to sit down, the other room with just one stall to sit down.

Comment: @gnasher729 yes, but the urinals are open. Once you enter room number one, you are in the same room as the urinals. No doors.

Comment: The point of the sign is to ensure privacy for your gender is respected.  When nobody from your gender is present in the office, there's no need to respect those non-existent people's privacy.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337 although I failed to make it clear, I was posting, to anyone reading, a recommendation for gender-neutral restrooms. Also, I would never imply that a restroom that lacks stalls for every toilet/urinal should be considered for a gender-neutral restroom, for exactly the reason you specified! I also thought it was implicit in my comment that I was recommending that people construct *new* restrooms, but I can see now that it's definitely not implicit in my comment.

Comment: @Dukeling for sure. In my mind I was thinking single-stall restrooms due to the exact reason you said. I failed to make that explicit.

Answer (score 7):

Either way is fine, but it should be disclosed.  Mention that there is one bathroom with a single toilet that locks and the other is male only as there are 3 toilets in there.  Mention this to her and see if she has an issue with it.  If it's truly anti-hygienic then someone needs to learn how to aim better.  Men should lift the seat and aim.  I'm sure someone cleans the toilets, but if it's actually a hygiene issue then the men should not be allowed to use the women's.

It's an office, not a convenience store, there should be some hygiene there.